# 'npm build' does not generate project build on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: build, npm, webpack

OS: Windows 10 Pro
NPM Version: 3.8.6

So, I'm attempting to build a project with `npm build` but no project build output folder is generated, and the following error logs are generated:

```html
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-    cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@3.8.6
3 info using node@v6.1.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle learn-redux@1.0.0~prebuild: learn-redux@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle learn-redux@1.0.0~prebuild: no script for prebuild, continuing
7 info lifecycle learn-redux@1.0.0~build: learn-redux@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle learn-redux@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle learn-redux@1.0.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Projects\learn-redux\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Cmder\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\share\vim\vim74;C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\Scripts;C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5;C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Users\d0475\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\d0475\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\d0475\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Cmder
10 verbose lifecycle learn-redux@1.0.0~build: CWD:     C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Projects\learn-redux
11 silly lifecycle learn-redux@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run  clean && npm run build:webpack' ]
12 silly lifecycle learn-redux@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle learn-redux@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
14 verbose stack Error: learn-redux@1.0.0 build: `npm run clean && npm run build:webpack`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:239:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
15 verbose pkgid learn-redux@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Projects\learn-redux
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.14986
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
19 error node v6.1.0
20 error npm  v3.8.6
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error learn-redux@1.0.0 build: `npm run clean && npm run build:webpack`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the learn-redux@1.0.0 build script 'npm run clean && npm run build:webpack'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the learn-redux package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     npm run clean && npm run build:webpack
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs learn-redux
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls learn-redux
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My package.json reads as follows:

```html
  "scripts": {
    "build:webpack": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build:webpack",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=production mocha './tests/**/*.spec.js' --compilers js:babel-core/register",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "start": "node devServer.js"
  },
```

and my `webpack.config.prod.js` reads as follows:

```html
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [

    './client/reduxstagram'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': "'production'"
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
    // js
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client')
    },
    // CSS
    { 
      test: /\.styl$/, 
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'
    }
    ]
  }
};
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by changing:

```html
"build:webpack": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js",
```

to

```html
"build:webpack": "set NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js",
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and sometimes it is not so much the code.

Sometimes where you put the "main.js" and "app.js" files they go in the "src" folder of your project!

The file "main.js" is copied in the folder "src" and in that same folder is the sub-folder "components" "app.js"

That was the solution to my problem!